# Unity: Diagonal movement issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a test 2D game where my player moved from left to right and when he reached the end of the screen it would just transform on the other side. I had a change of heart and made my player move diagonally. It did work, but I have no idea how to make the player stop when it hits the end of the screen. I don't want it to transform on the other side, but rather just stop. So far all my results are either some glitching on the edges or not stopping at all. I have provided my PlayerController script. Right now my player moves diagonally and he will just continue after the edge of the screen. If anyone can assist me I would be very grateful. I never thought I will deal with diagonal movement, but I really want to learn how to do it.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 7;
    public float speedy = 7;

    public event System.Action OnPlayerDeath;
    float screenHalfWidthInWorldUnits;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        float halfPlayerWidth = transform.localScale.x / 2f;
        screenHalfWidthInWorldUnits = Camera.main.aspect * Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float velocity = inputX * speed;
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime); 
    }


    public void MoveRight()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, speedy);
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, -speedy);
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        rb.velocity =  Vector2.zero;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D triggerCollider)
    {
        if (triggerCollider.tag =="Box")
        {
            if (OnPlayerDeath != null)
            {
                OnPlayerDeath();
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to destroy player when reach to edge?

Comment: Why not just create colliders where you want to limit the player?

Comment: @MGDroid No, I just want him to stop. It worked fine when it was left or right, but with diagonal, I am missing something.

Comment: @IanH. I tied. I couldn't do it right for some reason. It again worked when going left or right but not for diagonal. Something with y I suspect.

Comment: Quick question, why are you moving the player with `transform.Translate` instead of using your methods `MoveRight()` and `MoveLeft()`? (This would currently ignore physics objects, such as colliders.)

Comment: @IanH. I am quite new to game dev, so I sometimes I go with what works. The test game is a mobile game and I had a problem with the touch controls with all other methods of programming my controls. And now I want my player to go diagonally(positive and negative) but can't seem to make him stop at the edge of the screen. I managed to make it hit the edge once, but then it just stopped moving diagonally and continued upwards, which completely destroyed the fixed positioning of the player.

Comment: @IanH. Any possible tips? I never thought collision can be a problem. I tried again and no matter what I do, it won't detect the collision. I added the code, tags all of it.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a short video/gif of the situation and the problem? I am kinda having a hard time to imagine what is going on.

Comment: @IanH. we.tl/Y2FXBqg20w I made a very short 18MB video. Uploaded it to WeTransfer.

Comment: @MGDroid Any tips?

Comment: I am unable to see where your boundary checking code base is. In Trigger function you matched it with box and trying to destroy. Is it a box in diagonal? Are you inside a box and checking? Please specify

Comment: @MGDroid I don't have boundaries because I am not sure how to make them. I had a box, with a tag, which was to collide and stop the player, but it ignores it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the player is at what you define as the border of the map.

If you check this for the x and y axis respectively, you can then lock his x or y axis to the border and not further.

Here is an example of a script I made earlier that does that.

If I understand you correctly you would like to be able to move diagonally. In my sample script below you can move both straight and diagonally, you can also warp between the edges or stop at the edges as you spoke of wanting to.

This script is a bit more advanced than what you need probably, so let me know if something about it confuses you.

Please note that if you set the boolean _ShouldWarp to false he will stop at the border, otherwise he will warp from edge to edge of the map.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float _Speed = 5f;
    public WorldBounds _WorldBounds;
    public bool _ShouldWarp; //If _ShouldWarp is false, will block players movement instead.

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        WarpIfAtBoundary();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * _Speed * horizontal);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * _Speed * vertical);
    }

    void WarpIfAtBoundary()
    {
        //X Axis
        //If player is at positive X boundary
        if (transform.position.x > (_WorldBounds.xPlus + _WorldBounds.xBuffer))
        {
            if (_ShouldWarp) //Teleport/warp player is set to enabled
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(_WorldBounds.xMinus, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }
            else //Otherwise keep player in border position
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(_WorldBounds.xPlus + _WorldBounds.xBuffer, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }
        }
        //Else if player is at negative X boundary
        else if (transform.position.x < (_WorldBounds.xMinus - _WorldBounds.xBuffer))
        {
            if (_ShouldWarp)//Teleport/warp player is set to enabled
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(_WorldBounds.xPlus, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }
            else //Otherwise keep player in border position
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(_WorldBounds.xMinus - _WorldBounds.xBuffer, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }
        }

        //Y Axis
        //If player is at positive Y boundary
        if (transform.position.y > (_WorldBounds.yPlus + _WorldBounds.yBuffer))
        {
            if (_ShouldWarp)//Teleport/warp player is set to enabled
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _WorldBounds.yMinus, transform.position.z);
            }
            else //Otherwise keep player in border position
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _WorldBounds.yPlus + _WorldBounds.yBuffer, transform.position.z);
            }
        }
        //Else if player is at negative Y boundary
        else if (transform.position.y < (_WorldBounds.yMinus - _WorldBounds.yBuffer))
        {
            if (_ShouldWarp)//Teleport/warp player is set to enabled
            { 
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _WorldBounds.yPlus, transform.position.z);
            }
            else //Otherwise keep player in border position
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _WorldBounds.yMinus - _WorldBounds.yBuffer, transform.position.z);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Set as serializable so it displays correctly in Unity's inspector window.
[System.Serializable]
public class WorldBounds
{
    [Header("Bounds")]
    public float xMinus = -9.4f;
    public float xPlus = 9.4f;
    public float yMinus = -9.4f;
    public float yPlus = 9.4f;
    [Header("BufferZone")]
    public float xBuffer = 1f;
    public float yBuffer = 1f;
}
```

EDIT:

> With your additions will I be able to assign the movement to my two buttons. One is up and right and the other is down and left.

```
        void Move()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * _Speed * horizontal);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * _Speed * horizontal);
    }
```

This should work to move diagonally left and down as well as up and right.

The change i made is to use the Horizontal input for both X and Y movement.

> I don't need the warp. Just to step at the defined borders

You can set the Warp boolean to false or remove the warp parts from the code then :-), should work.

Comment: The only thing before I try to implement it. With your additions will I be able to assign the movement to my two buttons. One is up and right and the other is down and left. Just a general question because I am quite able to screw things up.

Comment: From what I see. I don't need the warp. Just to step at the defined borders. I am not sure how, but I will try. Something with adding the bounds to my x and y positions. Also just to note. I don't want it to move straight. Just right upper diagonal and bottom left diagonal line.

Comment: Please see the edit I just made to the bottom of the original answer, where I try to address what you ask about.

Comment: Two small problems. I am not sure how to assign the Move() function to two buttons for up/right and down/left in the inspector. Now it works with the keyboard. Second, can you give me a tip towards scaling the borders? Right now my player does hit a border, but it's too big and If I change something on the buffer or bounds the spawn location moves for my player and so I can never adjust the borders properly.  Thank you!

Comment: What I use for input in the code is Unity's Input system, in this case what is called the Horizontal axis. That can normally be controlled with the A and D buttons or the left and right arrow keys.

Documentation page about input: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

To scale the border, move the player close to the border, see what his coordinate is and then apply that coordinate to the Bounds variable.

Not sure what you mean by the spawn location changing, it shouldnt have influence on the spawn location.

Comment: You might benefit from watching this video tutorial series on how to make a game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48anhmWxT54&list=PLadYLGMfR6LonchR8lGhJT90BweHNwqKC

There are 9 videos in the tutorial carefully explained.

It can be good to learn in that way as a beginner.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fic the borders. All that remains is that I still don't know how to divide the code into two separate buttons. I did a tutorial some time ago and they too used the Unity Input system, but I can't find anywhere how to make it into two buttons in the game instead of the keyboard keys.

Comment: You can make a variable of the type Keycode.

So for example:

    Public Keycode moveLeft;
    Public Keycode moveRight;

You can then set those buttons in the Inspector to be a specific button.

The Input class can then say 

    float direction = 0f;
    if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft))
    {
    direction = -1f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft))
    {
    direction = 1f;
    }

Then just use the direction variable instead of the "horizontal" variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165098/discussion-between-doh09-and-thenewbie).

Comment: It's certainly possible. That's what I just did with the Keycode example. But please go into the chat I started, it's linked in the previous comment of mine.